# INDY HttpGet returns Error 403 after first request

Tags: delphi, indy, http-status-code-403

I am using Delphi-XE5 with the bundled INDY Http Components to download a JSON file form a remote server to my computer and everything works as expected the first time I execute the code shown below, but upon subsequent executions, the application returns a 403 Forbidden error message and the file never gets downloaded form the server. The only way to get the download to work again is to exit and restart the application where I can run the code 1 more time before getting the 403 error message again and I am not sure why and was hoping someone with more experience could point me in the right direction.

Here is the code I am currently using to download the file to my pc.

```
var
  SS : TStringStream;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    IDHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-Client-Id: def4920');
    IDHTTP1.Get('https://example.com/some_json_file/', SS);
    SS.SaveToFile('test');
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The site that I am downloading the JSON from uses HTTPS and I have the INDY OPENSSL component linked to the IDHttp component on my form using the default settings of both components and the fact that I can download the file atleast once before erroring out shows that the credentials I am using are correct so the problem is not with that, but I don't know what else to check and could use some advise.

Comment: You are adding the same header multiple times. That's my only guess. Instead, try `IDHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Client-Id']:= 'def4920';`

Comment: That doesn't work either I am afraid. In fact, it doesn't even work the first time using the values parameter. The way it was before it worked at least once before erroring out. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Have you consulted with the vendor of the server you're connecting to?

Comment: No, because when I use the REST Debugger to download the same JSON file I do not get any error. I know that the debugger uses INDY as it's basis so this is why I am confused.

Comment: Could you possibly already have custom headers (of a different value) assigned to your `TIdHTTP` component in design-time? Or otherwise add a different header value at some other point? What happens if you comment out that line in your code above?

Comment: Try dropping a new `TIdHTTP` component in replacement of your current one.

Comment: I just created a brand new project and placed on the form the following componets: `Tbutton`, `Tedit`, `TIdHTTP`, and a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component. I then linked the OpenSSL component and IdHttp component together and placed the code above in the buttons Onclick event. I ran the app and it worked the first time but like before it errored out after that so I am really at a loss here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68242/discussion-between-user3839120-and-jerry-dodge).